# Vue js for loop - trigger js when new element added into dom

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I want to instantiate multiple **image croppers** using this library: https://fengyuanchen.github.io/cropper.js/

I iterate over ratios and add 4 images into DOM (i have 4 ratios - so one image per ratio):

```
<li v-for="ratio in ratios" :key="ratio.id">
    <div>
        <img v-bind:src="uploadRec.url" />
    </div>
</li>
```

I need to do something like this for every of those images:

```
const image = document.getElementById('image');
const cropper = new Cropper(image, {
  aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
  crop(event) {
    console.log(event.detail.x);
    console.log(event.detail.y);
    console.log(event.detail.width);
    console.log(event.detail.height);
    console.log(event.detail.rotate);
    console.log(event.detail.scaleX);
    console.log(event.detail.scaleY);
  },
});
```

I just cant wrap my head around it - how can I trigger some javascript when new element is added into dom by vue?

Comment: And where is "when new element is added into dom by vue" part?

Comment: @ikiK in  v-for loop ?

Comment: See how [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-cropperjs) component does it

Comment: @LawrenceCherone so I must use component for something like that? or like v-pre and skip vuejs?

Comment: Im asking you to show us vue app js code, not how you add components into html. IM asking how and when you add data. Take a look at this: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html under Lifecycle Diagram. May be of use to do what you want somewhere in middle..

Comment: you either turn the img into a component, or leverage on template refs and watch to perform side effects (run your cropper js code) when template refs becomes available

Answer (score 1):

You can either introduce your Image component, or bind a [template ref](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-template-refs.html#usage-inside-v-for) to each of your img element, and leverage on [watchEffect](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/reactivity-computed-watchers.html#watcheffect) to perform your cropper logic when the ref is added to the dom.

```jsx
<template>
  <li v-for="ratio in ratios" :key="ratio.id">
    <div>
        <img :ref="el => {if (el) { imgs[ratio.id] = el; }}"/>
    </div>
</li> 
</template>

<script>
  import {ref, reactive, watchEffect} from "vue";

  export default {
    name: "App",

    setup() {
            
        const ratios = ref([
        {id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}
      ]);
      
      const imgs = ref({});
      
      watchEffect(() => {
        for (let id in imgs.value) {
          const el = imgs.value[id];
          
        }
      });
      
      return {ratios, imgs};
    }
}
</script>
```

Of course you can also depend on `onMounted` hook if your ratios state does not change. This way you no longer need the `watchEffect`.